# VBA and properly handling Macro Security Level

Tags: vba, excel

**Q: What is recommended way of notifing user about loss of functionality unless User change macro security settings?**

*What I do now:*

I display warning on the first sheet user see after opening Workbook, with explanation why things WONT work unless proper settings are set.

And I hide it on start up. (Which wont happen unless settings are OK)

But its not perfect solution:

- That message is just one time. (While user could send that sheet to somebody else with different settings...)
- Hiding and showing those few rows is treaded by Excel as changing document. (So just opening and closing excel will generate Save changed warning!)

Comment: There's info out there on taking your concept further. Here's one post:http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/forcing-your-clients-to-enable-macros/

Comment: But the rows will only be hidden if macros are enabled (which means no loss of functionality). And even if that is the case, you could always set the saved state of the workbook to true in your `WorkBook_Open`code to kill the Save warning

Comment: @brettdj, when macros are enabled, I then must unhide those rows on closing excel -> worning about unsaved changes pops up.

Comment: @Doug Glancy post that link as separate answer. Its not perfect for me either. (As my app may contain any number of user defined sheets I do not want to hide, AND cause hiding/unhiding sheets will bring that "unsaved changes" warning too)

Comment: As I said, you can remove this warning using code. something like `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` on the `Worbook_Close` event

Comment: @brettdj Still do not know how it helps me. 1) User open up app 2) Change settings 3) Do some stuff 4) Wants to close without saving changes. How to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is best answer I could think off
(And big thx to @brettdj for suggestion!)

```
Sub HideMacroSecWarning()
    Status = ThisWorkbook.Saved
    Help.Range("Warning").rows.hidden = True
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = Status
End Sub

Sub ShowMacroSecWarning()
    Status = ThisWorkbook.Saved
    Help.Range("Warning").rows.hidden = False
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = Status
End Sub
```

Those are for showing and hiding macros. Saved state is preserved so only user actions can trigger "unsaved changes" dialogbox.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ShowMacroSecWarning
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call HideMacroSecWarning
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ShowMacroSecWarning
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Call HideMacroSecWarning
End Sub
```

Those assure that no matter the state of user settings warning will ALWAYS be displayed in SAVED FILE. (So even if for user Exel do not display that warning, somebody else who will open it on different machine will see that warning.)